# Use custom font in cocos2d-x v3 in iOS

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to use a custom font in Cocos2d-x v3 in iOS.
I'm following these steps:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Use_Custom_TTF_Font_on_iOS

But when I run the app, the font doesn't appears (the label works properly, expect for the font).

This is my code:

```
auto playerLabel = LabelTTF::create("Player", "Aller.ttf", 32);
    playerLabel->setPosition(Point(40, visibleSize.height - playerProfile->getContentSize().height - 10));
    playerLabel->setColor(ccc3(1,1,1));
    playerLabel->setAnchorPoint(Point(0.0f, 0.0f));
    this->addChild(playerLabel,5);
```

Comment: i believe for iOS, .ttf is not required. you can just use "Aller" in create method

Comment: Also if you are using fonts/Aller.ttf in your plist file, remove the path "fonts/" instead just use Aller.ttf in the plist file

Answer (score 1):

Just to close the question.
The answer given by @essess in the commens worked perfectly.

**Answer:**

if you are using fonts/Aller.ttf in your plist file, remove the path "fonts/" instead just use Aller.ttf in the plist file